# Passing Complex Object to .netcore1.1 Webapi though Query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, query-string

I'm trying to pass a complex object though the query string but for some reason its not working.  I have a complex object that looks like this:

```
public class QueryOptions
{
    public QueryParameter[] Parameters = new QueryParameter[0];
}
```

And I've tried to sent it a few ways but nothing is working:

My webapi method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<TDTO[]> GetList([FromQuery] QueryOptions queryOptions)
{
    return await this._service.GetList(queryOptions);
}
```

I've tried with and with out the FromQuery Attribute neither are working.
The url queries looks like this :

> /api/users?Parameters[0].PropertyName=FirstName&Parameters[0].Value=GTitzy&Parameters[0].FilterCondition=0

I've also tried with the name of the object appened to the beginning.  The request gets sent but the queryOptions always have no parameters.

How can I pass this complex object through the query string?

Comment: Don't. Use body and form.post().

Comment: That is not going to work and GET should not be used to SEND complex objects. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nkosi I'm trying to allow dynamic filtering on basic properties,  I'm trying to pass a query options dto to  filter my lists.  I wanted to use the get so you can maintain the URL when passing it to a user

Comment: If I make it a post thought users won't be able to pass the URL around and I didn't feel like using odata, should I write a custom model binder or do you have anything in mind

Comment: @johnny5 Custom model binder would be best given the complexity of the object in question

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895485/required-query-string-parameter-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

```
public class QueryParameter {
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string FilterCondition { get; set; }
}
```

You need to update your model to expose public properties for `[FromQuery]` to know what to bind to.

```
public class QueryOptions {
    public QueryParameter[] Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

You should also consider reading [Model Binding: Customize model binding behavior with attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: I forgot to make my class use properties!

Comment: @johnny5 you should consider looking for a simpler way to pass your query options. IMO this is over complicating things

Comment: yeah I've been looking for a good way, but ending up doing it this way because, this is working generically for all my crud entities,  Its applying universal filtering and and search api, and I'm crunched on my deadline