# Can you mark an "optional" query as required in Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

I have an action on my controller that takes required parameters, but I need them to be *technically* optional in C#. For example:

```
public class MyController {
        /// <summary>Retrieves all of the  assets that match the given criteria.</summary>
        /// <param name="required">First required param.</param>
        /// <returns>A set of assets.</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(MyModel))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(
            int? requiredA = null, 
        )
        {
            // Do stuff if a is null
            return Ok(results);
        }
}
```

I tried setting a Required attribute on the parameter, but that didn't change anything (`[Required] int? requiredA = null`). I also tried messing around with the `<param>` tag in the XML docs, but Intellisense didn't return anything and the documentation on that only lists `name` as a valid attribute. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: "Technically optional" is optional.  Why does the parameter need to be *technically* optional?

Comment: I posted the use case as a separate question, since I'm sure there's a better way to achieve what I'm looking for, but I'd still like to know if it's possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63415110/can-you-make-missing-queries-in-a-net-webapi-result-in-a-bad-request-instead-of

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895485/required-query-string-parameter-in-asp-net-core