# Can you make missing queries in a .NET WebApi result in a bad request instead of a 404?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller:

```
public class MyController {
        /// <summary>Retrieves all of the  assets that match the given criteria.</summary>
        /// <param name="parentId">Id of parent entity.</param>
        /// <returns>A set of assets.</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(MyModel))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(
            int parentId, 
        )
        {
            // ...
            return Ok(results);
        }
}
```

The `parentId` is required, but if the user goes to `/route`, it returns a 404. Is there a way to intercept this response and throw a Bad Request, notifying users of the missing Id instead? I tried making the parentId optional and then throwing the bad request myself, however that does not work nicely with Swagger and lead me down this rabbit hole: [Can you mark an "optional" query as required in Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414914/can-you-mark-an-optional-query-as-required-in-swagger)

Comment: just wondering why? its a bad request...

Comment: You could make a parameterless method that returns an error of your choosing, and hide it from swagger with `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`?